# KVM Bridge strangness - no IPADDR in interface but shown in 'if ADDR' & loose ssh access when run virt-install

Tags: centos

This is odd, the main interface (enp7s0) has an IP address.  There is no IP address in the ifcfg-enp7s0, its in ifcfg-br0. Things seems to be working but when I set this up on my test server I did not get a IP on the main interface.  Any ideas?

UPDATE: actually almost all is working.  **When I do virt-install I lose ssh access to the server**.  The existing terminals conected via ssh still work, its the new ones that will not connect, 22 time out error.  If I kill the virt-install I can ssh in on new term.

ifcfg-enp7s0

```
DEVICE="enp7s0"
NM_CONTROLLED="no"
ONBOOT=yes
#HWADDR=2c:4d:54:43:92:df
TYPE=Ethernet
BOOTPROTO=none
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=yes
IPV6INIT=no
NAME="System enp7s0"
BRIDGE=br0
```

ifcfg-br0

```
DEVICE="br0"
NM_CONTROLLED="no"
ONBOOT=yes
#HWADDR=2c:4d:54:43:92:df
TYPE=Bridge
BOOTPROTO=static
IPADDR=xxx.171.204.107
NETMASK=255.255.252.0
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=yes
IPV6INIT=no
```

route-br0

```
xxx.171.204.1 dev br0
default via xxx.171.204.1
```

ip addr

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp7s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master br0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 2c:4d:54:43:92:df brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet xxx.171.204.107/22 brd 213.171.207.255 scope global enp7s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::2e4d:54ff:fe43:92df/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: enp8s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 2c:4d:54:43:92:e0 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: br-369501bb177f: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default
    link/ether 02:42:22:7c:d4:52 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.18.0.1/16 brd 172.18.255.255 scope global br-369501bb177f
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::42:22ff:fe7c:d452/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
32: virbr0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:56:31:0e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.122.1/24 brd 192.168.122.255 scope global virbr0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
33: virbr0-nic: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master virbr0 state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:56:31:0e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
36: br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 2c:4d:54:43:92:df brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet xxx.171.204.107/22 brd 213.171.207.255 scope global br0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::2e4d:54ff:fe43:92df/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Answer (score 0):

OK worked it out.  I had ifconfg-enp8s0 I forgot to remove from a previous try (turns out Fasthosts did not actually connect second NIC). And stupidly I had left DEVICE="enp7s0".  Removed file and all worked great.